# How to compare only part of text that contains digits?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have list made by with

```
driver.find_elements_by_*
```

and for example while printed with .text this list looks like this:

```
17.4K gems
8.5K gems
11.4K gems
9.7K gems
```

Can I somehow compare only part with number without creating new list with extracted numbers so it will work like code below?

```
if gems[x].text > '10.5':
   print(gems[x].text)
```

Comment: can you please provide us the list in raw format?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Example list:

```
name_list = ["17.4K gems", "8.5K gems", "11.4K gems", "9.7K gems"]

for name in name_list:
    split_name = name.split("K")
    print(split_name[0])
```

Output:

```
17.4
8.5
11.4
9.7
```

Then, you can compare like:

```
if split_name[0] > '<some value>':
    <condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by splitting your strings at the 'K' letter, e.g. using

```
import re
re.split('K', element)
```

and compare the content of the first part with 10.5. Note that this will be a string so conversion to float will be required first: `float(re.split('K', element)[0])`.

Finally if you want to write this in a comprehensive way, you will end up with a new list, that can be printed in different ways.

Example:

```
myList=['17.4K gems', '9.8K gems', '0.9K gems', '15.3K gems']
for el in [item for item in myList if float(re.split('K',item)[0]) > 10.5]:
  print(el)
```

which returns

```
17.4K gems
15.3K gems
```

Comment: As shown by @AbiSaran in  a different answer here, you could indeed do `item.split('K')` instead of `re.split('K',item)`.

Answer (score -1):

try this to get list of numbers

```
name_list = ["17.4K gems", "8.5K gems", "11.4K gems", "9.7K gems"]
nums = [float(item.split('K')[0]) for item in name_list]
print(nums)
```